# loadGraphModel model json from local device ERROR React Native

Tags: react-native, tensorflow, tensorflow.js, tensorflowjs-converter

i use loadGraphModel model json from local device ERROR React Native
My function of me:
CODE:

```
async function predictModellocal1() {
        console.log("[+] Application started")
        const tfReady = await tf.ready();
        tf.device_util.isMobile = () => true
        tf.device_util.isBrowser = () => false
        console.log("[+] Loading  face detection model")
        const modelUrl =
              'https://storage.googleapis.com/tfjs-models/savedmodel/mobilenet_v2_1.0_224/model.json';
        console.log("[+] Loading  face detection model")
        const modelPath=
            'D:\\Code\\ReactNative\\appAI-mobilenet\\assets\\facenet\\weights_manifest.json';
        const modelPath1  = await require("./assets/facenet/weights_manifest.json");
        const model = await tf.loadGraphModel(modelPath1);
        console.log("[+] Loading model: done")
        const imgB64 = await FileSystem.readAsStringAsync(selectedImage.localUri, {
            encoding: FileSystem.EncodingType.Base64,
        });
        const imgBuffer = tf.util.encodeString(imgB64, 'base64').buffer;
        const raw = new Uint8Array(imgBuffer)
        const imageTensor = decodeJpeg(raw);
        const img = tf.image.resizeBilinear(imageTensor, [224,224])
        console.log(' Đã chạy')
        const img4d = img.reshape([1, 224, 224, 3,]);
        const prediction = await model.predict(img4d);
        const kq = getTopKClasses(prediction, 5)
        console.log(kq,'kq')
        setTextshow('ok')
    }
```

modelUrl working well. I get model from google api.

```
const modelUrl ='https://storage.googleapis.com/tfjs-models/savedmodel/mobilenet_v2_1.0_224/model.json';
```

But i want to loadGrapModel from local to can use offine :

```
const modelPath='D:\\Code\\ReactNative\\appAI-mobilenet\\assets\\facenet\\weights_manifest.json';
const modelPath1  = await require("./assets/facenet/weights_manifest.json");
```

I use Expo CLI for my app.
Thanks All

```
Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read
    at Object.readSync (fs.js:523:3)
    at tryReadSync (fs.js:348:20)
    at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:385:19)
    at UnableToResolveError.buildCodeFrameMessage (D:\Code\ReactNative\appAI-mobilenet\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph\ModuleResolution.js:304:17)
    at new UnableToResolveError (D:\Code\ReactNative\appAI-mobilenet\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph\ModuleResolution.js:290:35)
    at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (D:\Code\ReactNative\appAI-mobilenet\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph\ModuleResolution.js:168:15)
    at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (D:\Code\ReactNative\appAI-mobilenet\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph.js:353:43)
    at D:\Code\ReactNative\appAI-mobilenet\node_modules\metro\src\lib\transformHelpers.js:271:42
    at D:\Code\ReactNative\appAI-mobilenet\node_modules\metro\src\Server.js:1097:37
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)

[Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: url.match is not a function. (In 'url.match(HTTPRequest.URL_SCHEME_REGEX)', 'url.match' is undefined)]
at http://192.168.31.235:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:184464:20 in isHTTPScheme
at [native code]:null in every
at httpRouter@http://192.168.31.235:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:184474:26 in <unknown>
```

Comment: I am not familiar with the format your model weights are in `/facenet/weights_manifest.json`. Is this model converted from tensorflowjs-converter?

Comment: yes. it was converted from tensorflowjs-converter.

Comment: Or I load model.json of mobilenet from folder assets.                                              
 const modelPath1  = await require("./assets/model.json");                                         
It also has the same error as above. It doesn't seem to be accessible from assets using      LoadGrapModel(modelPath)

Comment: Could you check the path to the model again? This error means that you are trying to read in a dir instead of a file.

Comment: path file of me is ok.

Comment: Include how the model was converted using tensorflowjs-converter.

Comment: i have a error : [TypeError: url.match is not a function. (In 'url.match(HTTPRequest.URL_SCHEME_REGEX)', 'url.match' is undefined)] error when load mode.json from asset

Comment: i dowload it at:                                                                                                          https://tfhub.dev/google/tfjs-model/imagenet/mobilenet_v2_140_224/classification/2/default/1

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `await` keyword when setting the path to the `modelPath1`:

```
const modelPath1 = require("./assets/facenet/weights_manifest.json");
const model = await tf.loadGraphModel(modelPath1);
```

Comment: error: 
[Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: url.match is not a function. (In 'url.match(HTTPRequest.URL_SCHEME_REGEX)', 'url.match' is undefined)]

Comment: Comment out everything past the code I included and check that it works